# Any debug tool in opera (like firebug in firefox)?

Tags: firefox, web-applications, firebug, opera, opera-dragonfly

Like firefox has **firebug** as a efficient tool for web application developer, I am wondering is there any similar tool in opera which is for web developers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Opera you can use DragonFly

> Opera Dragonfly 1.0 is included by default with the Opera browser.
>   Launch Opera Dragonfly with Ctrl + Shift + I on Windows and Linux, or
>   ⌘ + ⌥ + I on Mac. Alternatively, target a specific element by right
>   clicking in the page and selecting "Inspect Element".

[image]

http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/

A video on youtube http://www.youtube.com/v/BeTzJ-HGLo4?version=3&modestbranding=1&rel=0

> Opera Dragonfly is a cross device, cross platform debugging
>   environment for the Opera browser-debug JavaScript, inspect and edit
>   CSS and the DOM

More Info http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/documentation/

Alternatively you can also use Firebug Lite in Opera

http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Answer (score 1):

There is DragonFly. You can start it by right-click -> Inspect Element