# How to use/open/enable Dragonfly?

Tags: opera, opera-dragonfly

I want to use the Dragonfly debugger for the Opera browser.  I'm not sure what I did wrong.  I downloaded the opera browser, but when I click inspect element, I just get the firebug debugger.  And I'm not just confusing one for the other, because I've used Dragonfly on another machine before.  Do I have to download another extension?  I'm using a Max OS X 10.7.5.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: most probably, what you are getting is Chrome Developer Tools, and not Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Opera cannot communicate with the native Firebug (from Firefox), so it sounds like you've downloaded Opera, installed the [Firebug Lite](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/firebug-lite-button/) extension, and are starting this extension (via the button it installs) instead of Opera's built-in Dragonfly (which you start via right-click and "Inspect element", or by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or the Mac equivalent). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7078058/983430) for more details.